# How to read the empty cell in a PDF file in ASP.net

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox

I am able to read a pdf file using PDFBOX in my ASP.net application but it is not adding space for an empty cell in a table, So how to read empty fields from a pdf file using PDFBOX in C#. Is there any other method to read the pdf file .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to pull off this sort of thing if you know exactly where the text *should* be in advance and can get the locations of the text as you extract it.

If you don't know in advance where the rows and cells are, you'll have to guess based on the text locations.  This will not be easy.

In general, extracting data from PDF is ill advised.  PDFs don't have a concept of "tables" (unless the PDF creator goes well out of there way to use "Marked Content", which is still rare).  PDFs have lines, glyphs, and images (a pile of pixels).  It is Very Hard to extract formatting from that information... and sometimes it is all but impossible.

I don't know if PDFBox will give you the locations of extracted text, but iTextSharp will.